# A method to know the color code in an image

Tags: image, image-processing, adobe, photoshop, color-codes

Is there any way, I can know the exact color code of in image using photoshop ? For example in the following image :

[image]

I want to know the exact color code of orange color applied. Is there any way I can directly know using photoshop ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From memory as I don't have my PS at work -

1 - Pipette the colour

2 - Double click the colour in your foreground colour section

Should show you the colour in a variety of formats, including html codes

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to find out the exact "color code" of any type of color within the image, is to:

Double click the foreground or background color box at the bottom of the toolbox, this will then pop-up a window that is called 'color picker'. You then want to move it to the side so you can see the image, and if you notice when you move your cursor over the image the cursor will then look like the 'eye dropper' tool. Click once in the area of color you want, then you will notice in the 'color picker' window the code will change down at the bottom titled with a "#". That will be your number, in your case the exact color of orange is 'fb844a'.

[image]